# Determining if the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\, |\, |{\bf Im}\,z| \lt 1 \text{ and } |{\bf Re}\,z| \lt 1\}$ is a star domain.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Determine if this set is a star domain. Justify your answer.

> $$\{z\in\mathbb{C}\, |\, |{\bf Im}\,z| \lt 1 \text{ and }  |{\bf Re}\,z| \lt 1\}$$

Can you please help me approach the question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I denote your set by $G$. We have $0 \in G$.

Show that if $z \in G$ then $tz \in G$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.

Then you are done.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your quick response. I'm not too sure how to do that. Can you show me how to start this?

Comment: If $t \in [0,1]$ and $z \in G$, then show that $|Im(tz)|<1$ and $|Re(tz)|<1$

Comment: Does this mean the set is a star domain?

Comment: what is the definition of " star domain "  ???

Comment: This is what I have so far; Let $w, z$ $\in$ $G$. The path $p:[0,1]$ -> $\mathbb C$ defined by $t$ -> (1-t) w +tz

has the property that for every $t$ we have that $Re$($p(t)$)= $Re$($(1-t)w+tz$) = ($1-t$)$Re(w)$ +$tRe(z)$ $\lt$($1-t$)1 + $t(1)$ = 1. Hence, $Re$($p(t)$) $\in$ G

for every $t$ $\in$ [0,1]. Is this centered at 1 or everywhere. I am not too sure if this is right?

Comment: I've been trying to use the definition of a star domain which is 'A domain D is a star domain with centre $z_0$ if for each point $w ∈ D$ the entire line segment [$z_0,w$] = $wt$ + $z_0$ $(1−t)$|$t$ ∈ $[0,1]$ lies within D. How can I use this to answer the question?

Comment: Show that in the set above, the point $z_0=0$ works.